# Webcam simulator for Linux?

Tags: linux, video, webcam

I'm looking for a program that simulates a webcam under Linux, so I can broadcast a video file through my webcam, e.g. in Skype. I'd prefer a way to do this through the terminal, but GUI applications are acceptable if that's all there is.

Webcam Studio used to be an option, but [the website](http://www.ws4gl.org/) appears to be down, and the only information I can find says it's Ubuntu only (which doesn't make sense to me). I use Debian Linux with dwm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WS4GL, aka Webcam Studio, had moved to Google Code, but since that is shutting down, the project is now hosted on [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webcamstudio/). The last update there is from 2015-09-28. The last import on [Ubuntu Launchpad](https://code.launchpad.net/~webcamstudio/webcamstudio/trunk) was on 2015-10-15, so it seems to be active.

I don't think it's for Ubuntu only, since you'll find [Debian packages](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webcamstudio/files/Binaries/Beta/Debian%20%28Ubuntu%29/) as well.

It it licensed under GPL3.

Comment: it's also avaliable in [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~webcamstudio/+archive/ubuntu/webcamstudio-dailybuilds): `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webcamstudio/webcamstudio-dailybuilds`, `sudo apt-get update`, `apt-get install webcamstudio`

Answer (score 0):

There are several programs that provide this functionality. [Webcamoid](https://webcamoid.github.io/) is a cross-platform option that supports "virtual cameras" which is what you're looking for.

Similarly, [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/), combined with the [obs-v4l2sink plugin](https://github.com/CatxFish/obs-v4l2sink), can emulate much of the functionality that [OBS Virtual Cam](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/obs-virtualcam.949/) can provide (quite well, in my experience) on Windows.