# How can I achieve this "nametag" effect on video calls (Zoom and Google Meet)?

Tags: video-conferencing, webcam, meetings, zoom

I like this idea that I see at https://warmly.ai/p/nametags but I want to be able to full customize one for myself in Photoshop.

[image: video call with nametag]

I tried making a .png file with transparency and using that as my "background" for Zoom and Google Meet, but had 2 unacceptable consequences:

- it treated the transparent part of the png as white
- it showed my nametag features "behind" my body instead of in front

How can I achieve my goal?

I'm curious for Windows 10, MacOS, and Ubuntu, since I have computers using each.

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), etc. If you're looking for software, please [see here](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) and **[edit]** your post accordingly. Especially we'd need to know what OS must be supported. e.g. OBS might work for you (which basically mixes different input and provides it as output again), but I haven't used it myself.

Comment: Ok, I added a line: "I'm curious for Windows 10, MacOS, and Ubuntu, since I have computers using each."

Comment: Well, price tag would help, too ;) And did you take a look at [OBS](https://obsproject.com/)? [This answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/77252/185) suggests it could fit your needs (mixing sources like your nametags with your cam input and providing this as a virtual camera). A more detailed [answer here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/74002/185) confirms that with a step-by-step guide. More OBS answers [in these search results](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?tab=Relevance&q=obs%20is%3aa),